# Use SQL to combine files from different locations in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to combine different files from different file locations into one spread sheet. I find some code online through which I was able to use SQL in VBA to combine them if they are from the same location:

Excerpt of the code is here:

```vb
Sub sample()

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.path & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

    StrSQL="SELECT * FROM samplesheet.csv"

    objRecordSet.Open StrSQL

...

End Sub
```

In my code above I can specify only one location as Data Source. Is there any other way to write the SQL code so it can work with multiple locations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the multiple `LEFT JOIN` query assuming all CSV files share the same *ID* field. **NOTE**: SQL queries requires parentheses pairings for every `FROM` table and `JOIN` table.

```vb
StrSQL= "SELECT * " _
         & " FROM ((samplesheet.csv t1 " _
         & " LEFT JOIN [text;database=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "].samplesheet2.csv AS t2" _
         & "    ON t1.ID = t2.ID)" _
         & " LEFT JOIN [text;database=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "].samplesheet3.csv AS t3" _
         & "    ON t1.ID = t3.ID)"
```

Do note there is a finite limit of `JOIN` statements allowed for any JET/ACE Engine query like this one which depends on data.

For large number of CSV files, consider iterating through directory. Below copies each recordset to adjacent placement by columns. **NOTE**: no *ID* joins are used here due to iterative process. Data is simply placed side by side.

```vb
Dim objConnection As Object, objRecordSet As Object
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim csvFile As String, StrSQL As String

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                   "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ";" & _
                   "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

csvFile =  Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*csv")

Do While Len(csvFile) > 0

    StrSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & csvFile & "] ORDER BY ID;"

    ' INITIALIZE RECORDSET
    Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")    
    objRecordSet.Open StrSQL, objConnection

    ' SAVE TO WORKSHEET
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        .Range(.Cells(1, lastColumn), .Cells(1, lastColumn)).CopyFromRecordset objRecordSet 
    End With

    ' UNINITIALIZE RECORDSET
    objRecordSet.Close
    Set objRecordSet = Nothing

    csvFile = Dir
Loop

objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a try!

Comment: This allows me to join several csv files horizontally. Sorry, I was not very clear in my question. I need to use LEFT JOIN to combine the files.

Comment: Then change `UNION` to `LEFT JOIN` calls and for iteration change row for column placement. But for many files, I would advise importing all CSVs in a database like MS Access and then connect as needed for dump out to MS Excel.

Comment: The first code you have posted does not really work for me. It says syntax error after the FROM clause.

Comment: As noted, multiple joins require parentheses in this SQL dialect. And all tables are related to first table, *t1* (not *t2* with *t3* but each to *t1*). Post actual  csv data sample of files including IDs and filenames/fields as identifiers with spaces and special characters need to be bracketed, how many files, actual ttempted SQL, etc. I'm working in the dark here and gave a generic answer.

Comment: sorry I am not very familiar with the function here. Looks like I can't post my complete code. My objective is to combine two csvs from two different locations. Say sample1.csv under C:\ and sample2.csv under D:\. I need to LEFT join them on a common ID column. The VBA code I have found online can only let me specify the SQL server when I open the connection (through the parameter "data source"). But I need to be able to specify each input file separately. Hope that is clear.

Comment: In the `JOIN` approach in solution here, you can point to other file paths for CSVs. Simply change `ThisWorkbook.Path` to hard coded path or a different VBA variable.

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work when I try to recordset. It throws me a syntax error after FROM. In fact, I can't even make the UNION one work by only change the file names. Would you mind posting a complete code like you did for merging cvs files?

Comment: Check the history of this answer by clicking the edited date to see the `UNION` version. It would help if you post your actual attempt. You as the OP can always edit your post *anytime* you want. Click **edit** link below tags of your posted question.

Comment: I tried your the first syntax you posted (the left join one). It turns out that I erroneously added a space in between! After removing the space, it is actually working now. Thanks a lot!